# Katalon Studio Starting Browser opening Problem

Tags: katalon

I have a problem that I can't solve:

When I start my Test Cases, first what happens a new Chrome Opens with a URL I never mentioned anywhere.
URL: https://id.atlassian.com/login?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fkatalon.atlassian.net%2Flogin%3FredirectCount%3D1%26application%3Djira&application=jira

After the URL is loaded, the browser closes automatically and now my real URL opens and my tests begins....

How can I skip the opening of the first URL?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards 
Fanakk

Comment: This sounds like something you need to take up with Atlassian - since they make Katalon Studio, and this looks like a redirect intended to make sure you're using a registered copy

Comment: is katalon studio not free?

Comment: It is free, but you still need to activate/register you copy according to https://www.katalon.com/sign-up/

Comment: i signed and everything but still when in open tastecase the atlassian page first opens...

Answer (score 0):

Based on the URL provided, I am assuming you are using one of Katalon Studio's sample projects: "*Sample Jira UI Tests Project*".

If you go to the *default Profile* section, you will see that `GlobalVariable.URL` is set to "https://katalon.atlassian.net".

Next, that global variable is called inside of the *test listener* that executes before each test case:

```
@BeforeTestCase
def beforeTestcase(TestCaseContext testCaseContext) {
    WebUI.openBrowser('');
    WebUI.maximizeWindow();
    WebUI.navigateToUrl(GlobalVariable.URL);
}
```

So, even if you never mentioned the URL, it is the value of a global variable that is called inside of a test listener that gets called before each test case.